# Malloc on a userinput struct array in a struct array

Tags: c, struct, malloc

```
struct Card
{
    char *color;
    int value ;

};
struct Player
{
    Card* Hand;
    Card* deck;
};
```

```
struct Player player[MaximumNumberOfPlayers] = { //
    {(struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card)), (struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card))}, //
    {(struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card)), (struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card))}, //
    {(struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card)), (struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card))}, //
    {(struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card)), (struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card))}, //
    {(struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card)), (struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card))}, //
    {(struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card)), (struct Card*) malloc(numberOfCards * sizeof(struct Card))}};
```

Hello code above works as it should but, is there a proper way to create an array of structs(Player) with user input array of struct(Card) in it?

```
struct Player player[MaximumNumberOfPlayers] = { 
    {(struct Card*) malloc((numberOfCards) * sizeof(struct Card)), 
     (struct Card*) malloc((numberOfCards) * sizeof(struct Card))}};

for (int i = 1; i < gameSettings.numberOfPlayers; i++)
{
  player[i] = player[i - 1];
}
```

was trying something like this but it couldn't work and also is there a way to make a player struct array also from user input?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
struct Player player[MaximumNumberOfPlayers];

for (int i = 0; i < gameSettings.numberOfPlayers; i++)
{
    player[i]->deck = malloc((numberOfCards) * sizeof(struct Card));
}
```